# Принудительное завершение функции JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Как сделать принудительный выход из функции, например:

```
function some(){
    var а = 3;
    if (a == 1){ 
        а = 2;
    } else {
        // здесь выход из функции, т.е. запуска any() уже не будет
    }
    any();
}
```

Comment: Ну и вопросы у вас...

Comment: Ну а че, если человек не знает... Кого ему еще спрашивать...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

выход из функции:

```
 return;
```

Comment: Благодарю :)